# JQuery: AJAX Not Showing Result From Server

Tags: jquery, express

I am using jQuery to perform Ajax, and then construct a JavaScript `object` which will be sent back to browser. However, after the server send the data, the data does not show up in the browser. Here is the code:

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/home",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(//sent data...)
  }).done(function(result){
      console.log(result.html);
      console.log(result.number);
  })
```

**ExpressJS**

```
router.post("/home", function(req, res){
    User.findById(id).exec(function(err, user){
        res.render("home", {user: user}, function(err, html){
            res.send({html: html, number: 123});
            console.log({html: html, number: 123});
        }
    });
});
```

In the Express code, the "html" is a bunch of rendered `html` code. When I `console.log` in Express, the terminal shows up the expected data. However, on the browser side, both `console.log(result.html)`and`console.log(result.number)` are not showing anything in the browser's console. I am not too sure where it goes wrong.

Comment: remove `console.log({html: html, number: 123});` from expressJs code as well as add "error" param in your "done" function:

`function(err, result) { 
    console.log(result.html);
    console.log(result.number);
}`

Comment: Yes I have done that. The code is edited here so that it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to test it right now, but I think your should add an "error" param in your "done" function:

```
function(err, result) { 
    console.log(result.html);
    console.log(result.number);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done that. The code is modified here so that it's easier to understand.